Continuous representative of Sobolev function on triangle set
According to Morrey`s inequality $$||u||_{C^{0,\gamma}(U)}\leq C\cdot ||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)}$$there is a continuous representative for every $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$. $U$ is supposed to be a bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary.
Does this statement also hold for domains without a Lipschitz boundary? For example:
$$\Omega:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0<x<1, x^r<|y|<x^{2r}\} $$
If this statement holds on such sets, how can it be proven? If it does not hold, is there a counterexample?

The section "Generalizations" of the Wikipedia article on the Sobolev Inequality gives some other conditions for which this should also hold in some form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality

For proper choices of $p$ and $r$, something like $u(x,y) = x^s$ with proper $s < 0$ should be a counterexample.

Yes, this works but not for all values of $p$. I would recommend three references:

The papers of R. Adams "Some Integral Inequalities with Applications to the Embedding of Sobolev Spaces Defined Over Irregular Domains". It's also well written in his book "Sobolev spaves" in Chapter 4. He prove it for domains that are locally isomorphic to a polynomial cusp (domains that are metrically homogeneous).

In the book of V.Mazya "differentiable functions on bad domains" you can find with all details all the theory of Sobolev spaces (that we know on Lipschitz domains) for domains with an a homogeneous isolated singularity (this includes your case if we restrict to dimensions 2).

The paper of Guillaume Valette "On Sobolev spaces of bounded subanalytic manifolds" https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-024-02810-2. Here the Embeddings are proven for any bounded subanalytic manifolds. This is more general it says that as long as the singularities are tame (to be precised) and the sharpness are not exponential, then the theorem holds for a good value of $p$. Note that this conditions are necessary.


Remark: to prove it in your case, you can transform your cusp to a polynomial one (look at the book of R. Adams) by a bilipschitz homeomorphism and then you can use a cylindrical coordinate to transform your problem to a Hardy inequality.
